# Vue component throwing error: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, async-await

I am getting the following error in the console:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'render' of undefined
    at normalizeComponent (componentNormalizer.js?2877:24)...
```

The error does allow my view to be rendered and is caused by having the `async/await` on the `created` hook. This is very odd since I use this in many places in the application (mainly when calling an api on created).
Below is the full component, the only thing I can think of is the fact that this component is separated from the html.

```
<template src="./QuestionnairesList.html"></template>
<script>
import Header from "../../Global/Header";
import { questionnairesService } from "../../../services/questionnairesService";
import { diseasesService } from '../../../services/diseasesService';

export default {
  name: "QuestionnairesList",
  components: {
    Header
  },
   async created() {
    this.loading = true
    this.questionnairesFilter = await this.$store.getters.questionnairesFilter;
    this.$store.dispatch("searchQuestionnaires");
    // this.loading = false
  },
  data() {
    return {
      loading: null,
      questionnairesFilter: {},
    };
  },
  computed: {
    questionnaires() {
      this.loading = true
      const diseasesMap = this.$store.getters.diseasesMap;

      let ques = this.$store.getters.questionnaires.questionnaires || [];
      ques.forEach(preScreener => {
          let dxKey = diseasesService.getDiseaseKey(preScreener.disease);
          if (diseasesMap[dxKey]) {
                preScreener.disease_name = diseasesMap[dxKey].disease_name ;
                preScreener.sub_disease_name = diseasesMap[dxKey].sub_disease_name;
          }
      });
      this.loading = false
      return ques;
    },
    total() {
      return this.$store.getters.questionnaires.total;
    },
    pages() {
      return Math.ceil(
        this.$store.getters.questionnaires.total /
          this.questionnairesFilter.page_size
      );
    },
    IsLoading(){
        return this.loading
    }
  },


  methods: {
    onQueryKeyUp() {
      if (
        this.questionnairesFilter.query == "" ||
        this.questionnairesFilter.query.length > 1
      ) {
        this.questionnairesFilter.page = 1;
      }
      this.loading = true;
      this.$store.dispatch("searchQuestionnaires").then(() => {
        this.loading = false;
      });
    },
    onPageChange: function(pageNo) {
      this.loading = true
      this.questionnairesFilter.page = pageNo;
      this.$store.dispatch("searchQuestionnaires");
      this.loading = false
    },
    onNewQuestionnaire: function() {
      this.$store.dispatch(
        "setQuestionnaire",
        questionnairesService.getEmptyQuestionnaire()
      );
      this.$router.push({ name: "AddQuestionnaire" });
    },
    onQuestionnaireSelected: function(qu) {
      this.$router.push({ name: "EditQuestionnaire", params: { id: qu.id } });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: I think that is the issue. You are using await so created lifecycle won't execute till that api call is done, and hence mounted won't trigger, so you'll get similar error.

Comment: It works, there is no problem making an `async/await` inside of a lifecycle method, as I mentioned this works in many places in my app except here, in this case it is not even calling an api just the store.

Comment: Okay and if you remove async await, does it work ?

Comment: Yes it works but something is clearly wrong it shouldn't break the component

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem with code too, and it is a very irritating error as it gives you no clue whatsoever where the problem is!

I fixed it by adding my imported functions (in your case these are the "questionnairesService" and "diseasesService" functions), and add them as methods to my Vue component:

```
 methods: {
    questionnairesService,
    diseasesService

    onQueryKeyUp() {
    ...
```

Everywhere where you now call on the imported function, you instead call on the component method instead. So a current line like:

```
let dxKey = diseasesService.(....)
```

Then becomes

```
let dxKey = this.diseasesService.(...)
```

If you are working on your code in watch mode (as I do), then you have to stop and restart/rebuild you local application for this to work (as otherwise the render error will remain, even after modifying your code).
This worked for me like a charm, so maybe it works for you too.